# @synchronized vs. NSLock Instance vs. pthread_mutex_t

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I was watching a (2-year old) tutorial video on multithreading that stated that

- **NSLock instance** is 3x faster than using **@synchronized**
- **pthread_mutex_t** is 2x faster than an **NSLock instance** (effectively 6x faster than **@synchronized**)

Is this true? I haven't found anything that states with authority that it is, but I just wanted to poll some of you over at StackOverflow for your opinion and maybe solid proof.

Thanks!

**While I've already accepted the correct answer, future viewers of this question will find this article to be helpful: http://perpendiculo.us/?p=133**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that `@synchronized` includes the necessary try/catch logic to release the lock in an exception.  Once you add that logic the performance difference (which is not great in overall magnitude) will probably diminish significantly.

Comment: Also remember that @synchronized is a recursive lock, where as NSLock isn't.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII -- A fair point.  Probably not significant in most cases, but it could account for a bit of the performance difference -- `@synchronized` should be compared to NSRecursiveLock.

Comment: And what about pthread_mutex? I'm more interested in @Synchronized vs. pthread_mutex (been doing a lot of reading about the two, since I posted this question).

Comment: @ArtSabintsev -- pthread_mutex can be recursive or not, depending on how it's initialized.  Dunno if this affects its performance much.  (Likely the performance testing was done with a non-recursive mutex.)